# How to remove extra spaces on softkeyboard

Tags: android, margin, android-softkeyboard

I would like to know how to remove the ***top*** space/margin of a soft-keyboard.

---

For clearer picture, checkout the following screenshots:

**With space and without space:**

[image][image]

Comment: What are the input types for your username and password fields?

Comment: @MCeley Okay I think I got what you mean :) I will reconfigure the EditText options. Thanks for guiding!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "spacing" you're seeing is the autocomplete suggestion area. If you have an input type set to something as simple as `text` then you're going to get suggestions from the keyboard. Adding [`textNoSuggestions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS) to your `inputType` field will remove the suggestions area.

So for example:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/username_field"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:hint="@string/username" />
```

Or if you were already using something like `textCapWords` you can combine them like so:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/username_field"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions"
    android:hint="@string/username" />
```

Also, not sure if you are using it but just a heads up, you'll want to use `inputType="password"` for your password field.

Comment: +1 @MCeley Great info! I'm pretty sure others would benefit from your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Whatever your `inputType` is, add `|textNoSuggestions` to the end of it.

Comment: +1 That would the answer :) How could I forget this, Thanks @kcoppock