# How can i remove the extra space above the keyboard?

Tags: android

[image]
I have one activity an in this activity i have one BottomSheet.
In the bottomsheet layout there is button below the editext .
when keyboard is opened then in that case button is hiding behind the keyboard . and when i scroll then the button is visible. what i want is that the button should be always above the keyboard

Comment: post your xml code here.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432230/how-to-remove-extra-spaces-on-softkeyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is the autocomplete suggestion area of your softkeyboard. Use "**textNoSuggestions**" flag to your **inputType** property.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:hint="@string/inputName" />
```

Note: Here you can combine multiple flags in **inputType** like this,

```
    android:inputType="textPersonName|textNoSuggestions"
```

Just add **|textNoSuggestions** flag to the end of the **inputType** property.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in to your Edittext

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`